# Вылетает с ошибкой Terminated due to memory issue / Xcode / Unity

Tags: unity3d, xcode, vuforia

Игра работает нормально на Android, но выдает ошибку памяти и вылетает на iOS, все текстуры сжаты ASTC 6x6. 
Логи: https://pastebin.com/3utH8sXs

```html
Start Vuforia Engine
Vuforia.VuforiaARController:StartVuforia(Boolean)
Vuforia.VuforiaARController:StartAfterInitializationCompleted()
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
System.Delegate:DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[])
Vuforia.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 48)

cameraDeviceStartCamera
2019-06-04 12:43:30.775779+0900 ProductName[353:6113] INFO/AR(353) 2019-06-05 12:43:30: Starting camera with profile for iPhone7,2, 800.1
2019-06-04 12:43:30.789023+0900 ProductName[353:6113] ERROR/AR(353) 2019-06-05 12:43:30: VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping config step
2019-06-04 12:43:30.803335+0900 ProductName[353:6356] Deleting old image data @ 0x0
2019-06-04 12:43:30.803495+0900 ProductName[353:6356] Created new image data buffer @ 0x11ad14000 w/ 1382400 bytes
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Comment: Андрей, приветствую!
Удалось ли решить эту проблему? ... у меня аналогичная. Прошу подсказку!

Comment: Уже не помню как решил, вроде все сжал, все ресурсы